# VS 2019 why is intellisense slow for one project?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a tiny asp.net core project that was working ok for at least a year. Now, with no dependency changes, intellisense is incredibly slow. Maybe 15 seconds for it to appear. It is not a problem with other projects or solutions.

Rebuild All takes a long time to start. Nothing shows in the Build Console for a long time, eventually says "Rebuilt Starting" then its quick as usual. Whats it doing before it starts building? It must be related.

I have tried updating VS, rebooting etc. nothing will repair this slowness. What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Did you try deleting all temporary files? Make a copy of the project and delete all files except essential ones that can't be re-generated. Then try the intellisense.

Comment: How much do you have RAM? May be you should run projects without iis?

Comment: 128gb ram 12 core

Comment: Having a similar issue. Posted a [rant on VS reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/VisualStudio/comments/kxkyg1/anyone_else_notice_the_quality_of_vs_2019_is/) about it. Will post back here if I find anything.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by disabling all extensions

edit: this did not fix my problem. Closing and opening VS worked for a while, and then after a couple minutes, went back to the old problem!